# Flutter iOS: The bundle xxxxxxx contains disallowed nested bundles

Tags: ios, flutter, testflight

We recently upgraded to **Flutter 3.3.7** in our iOS project, and started to get the following error when uploading to TestFlight: `Asset validation failed Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'XXXXXXXXX' contains disallowed nested bundles.`

After several intents of understanding the root cause, we managed to create a minimum reproducible example, isolated from the rest of our project: https://github.com/alansteiman/FlutterExample

In this example, Flutter is integrated via Cocoapods using [this doc](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/ios/project-setup), as a dependency of a framework that is dynamically linked to the main app:
[image]